# Drag and Drop one Object class at a time

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

I am currently implementing `Drag and Drop` in a `UITextView`.

In the `UIDropInteractionDelegate` `canHande session:` method , I accept both Images and Text as the following:

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
    return session.hasItemsConforming(toTypeIdentifiers: [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeText as String])
}
```

But with this I have noticed a problem: If I'm dropping an image from the web, it accepts the `image` as expected but it also inserts the `image URL string`.

Is there any way to accept only one `class type` at a time?

```
func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {
    session.loadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (imageItems) in
        // image dropped
    }

    session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self) { (stringItems) in
        // text dropped
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `performDrop` delegate method, just grab the one you want. 

If there are both image **and** text available, pick the one you prefer.

Comment: The thing is that I may need both images and texts, but dropping images from the web they come with the image url string, which is detected as text as well